# Getting Quote Exact single input to work on quickswap

Tags: solidity, javascript, uniswap

So im trying to check how many tokens i'll get before i do a swap on quickswap like (1USDC -> 0.1655....LINK), I've tried to use:

```
try{
        const amountOut = await quickquoter.callStatic.quoteExactInputSingle(usdcToken, linkToken, fee, amountIn, sqrtPrice);
        console.log('Amount out quickswap: ', amountOut)
    }catch (error){
        console.error(error)
}
```

but i can't get the amount out of the trade, which is the best way to get the information before i do a swap?

Comment: What fee, and is there a pool with that pair and fee that exists? Check it at the factory to be sure.